# Android Camera API Advance Features

Tags: android, android-camera

I am to start working on an Android Custom Camera App. I just want to know is there any way to add the following features to my app:

- Beauty Level
- Red Eye Removal
- Acne Removal

I just want to know that if it is possible, can someone suggest or give me any idea how can code it into my app.

Though I am familiar with Android Camera API functions, and worked on several simple custom camera apps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For beginning, you can use [FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) to detect faces in the picture.For example , you can remove Red eyes by searching for Red pixels in the picture and try to decrease red level of them.And also , you can use OpenCV for detecting eyes.I found a sample for eye detection in [Here](http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/)